# Jaeger log warning messages saying no sender factories available

Tags: spring-boot, jaeger

I am trying to set up Jaeger to collect traces from a spring boot application. When my app starts up, I am getting this warning message

warn io.jaegertracing.internal.senders.SenderResolver - No sender factories available. Using NoopSender, meaning that data will not be sent anywhere!

I use this method to get the jaeger tracer

`@Bean
    Tracer jaegerTracer(@Value(defaulTraceName) String service) 
    {
        SamplerConfiguration samplerConfig = SamplerConfiguration.fromEnv().withType("const").withParam(1);
        ReporterConfiguration reporterConfig = ReporterConfiguration.fromEnv().withLogSpans(true);
        Configuration config = new Configuration(service).withSampler(samplerConfig).withReporter(reporterConfig);
    return config.getTracer();
}`

I have manually instrumented the code, but no traces show up in the jaeger UI. I have been stuck on this problem for a few days now and would appreciate any help given!

In my pom file, I have dependencies on jaeger-core and opentracing-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding dependency in pom file on jaeger-thrift.